# Generate positive real numbers from rpois()

Tags: r, simulation, poisson

I am trying to create a Poisson simulation using `rpois()`. I have a distribution of two decimal place interest rates and I want to find out if these have Poisson rather than a normal distribution.

The `rpois()` function returns positive integers. I want it to return two decimal place positive numbers instead. I have tried the following

```
set.seed(123)
trialA <- rpois(1000, 13.67) # generate 1000 numbers
mean(trialA)
13.22 # Great! Close enough to 13.67
var(trialA)
13.24 # terrific! mean and variance should be the same
head(trialA, 4) 
6 7 8 14 # Oh no!! I want numbers with two decimals places...??????

# Here is my solution...but it has a problem

# 1) Scale the initial distribution by multiplying lambda by 100

trialB <- rpois(1000, 13.67 * 100)

# 2) Then, divide the result by 100 so I get a fractional component
trialB <- trialB / 100
head(trialB, 4) # check results
13.56 13.62 13.26 13.44 # terrific !

# check summary results
mean(trialB)
13.67059  # as expected..great!
var(trialB)
0.153057 # oh no!! I want it to be close to: mean(trialB) = 13.67059
```

How can I use `rpois()` to generate positive two decimal place numbers that have a Poisson distribution.

I know that Poisson distributions are used for counts and that counts are positive integers but I also believe that Poisson distributions can be used to model rates. And these rates could be just positive integers divided by a scalar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you scale a Poisson distribution to change its mean, the result is no longer Poisson, **and** the mean and variance are no longer equal -- if you scale the mean by a factor `s`, then the variance changes by a factor `s^2`.

You probably want to use the Gamma distribution.  The mean of the Gamma is `shape*scale` and the variance is `shape*scale^2`, so you have to use `scale=1` to get real, positive numbers with equal mean and variance:

```
set.seed(1001)
r <- rgamma(1e5,shape=13.67,scale=1)
mean(r) ## 13.67375
var(r)  ## 13.6694
```

You can round to two decimal places without changing the mean and variance very much:

```
r2 <- round(r,2)
mean(r2) ## 13.67376
var(r2)  ## 13.66938
```

Compare with a Poisson distribution:

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
curve(dgamma(x,shape=13.67,scale=1),from=0,to=30,
      ylab="Probability or prob. density")
points(0:30,dpois(0:30,13.67),type="h",lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Ben for such a comprehensive answer.  Much appreciated !  Regards, Mark.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...